# MiniMax algorithm for 4 in a row

Tags: c#, console-application, minimax

I'm trying to implement minimax algorithm, but it isn't working, the computer is just making moves randomly. Here is the method Minimax and ComputerLogic.

```
static int MiniMax(int[,] board, int depth, bool isMax)
    {
        int len = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (board[i, j] == 0) len++;
            }
        }
        int best_score, score;
        if (WinVariants(board, 1))
        {
            best_score = -10;
            return best_score;
        }
        else if (WinVariants(board, 2))
        {
            best_score = 10;
            return best_score;
        }
        else if (len == 0)
        {
            best_score = 0;
            return best_score;
        }


        if (isMax)
        {
            best_score = -int.MaxValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if (board[i, j] == 0)
                    {
                        board[i, j] = 1;
                        score = MiniMax(board, depth + 1, false);
                        board[i, j] = 0;
                        best_score = Math.Max(best_score, score);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            best_score = int.MaxValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if (board[i, j] == 0)
                    {
                        board[i, j] = 2;
                        score = MiniMax(board, depth + 1, true);
                        board[i, j] = 0;
                        best_score = Math.Min(best_score, score);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return best_score;
    }
    static void ComputerLogic(int[,] grid, int VariantMove)
    {
        int[,] board = Copy(grid);
        int bestScore = -int.MaxValue, score;
        int len = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        if (len <= 2)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int x = rnd.Next(0, 7);
                int y = rnd.Next(0, 7);
                len++;
                if (grid[x, y] == 0)
                {
                    grid[x, y] = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        if (board[i, j] == 0)
                        {
                            board[i, j] = 1;
                            score = MiniMax(board, 0, false);
                            board[i, j] = 0;
                            if (score > bestScore)
                            {
                                bestScore = score;
                                grid[i, j] = 1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Too, i have method for Drawing my grid view 2d array.
If I choose the PC to go first, then it goes randomly. Otherwise, my mesh just isn't drawing.
I am guessing that I am not filling my main grid array correctly. Its copy is used for verification - board.

Can please help me with this problem?

Comment: What are your preliminary debugging observations (i.e., what have you found so far while debugging your program)?

Comment: In the MiniMax method, I always return either 0 or Int.MaxValue ...

Comment: That doesn't sound like much of a debug-effort. I think you'll need to do better than that while expecting others to do the same.

Comment: Sorry, just in this area for about 2 months, thanks

Comment: @saibel203 Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).